# Node Inspector Error while starting

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

I am getting error(PFB) while starting the node-inspector using command  `node-inspector &`

```
Node Inspector v0.6.2

   info  - socket.io started

   warn  - error raised: Error: listen EACCES

Cannot start the server at 0.0.0.0:8080. Error: listen EACCES.
```

Answer (score 18):

There is some other server running in port 8080. You can use [rc style configuration](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector#inspector-options) to change the port on which it has to listen. Or you can simply do

```
node-inspector --web-port=9999 &
```

Comment: Now I am able to start Node inspector after changing the port.
But when I open  http://127.0.0.1:8000/debug?port=5858 in Chrome , I am getting the bellow error..

Comment: Error Message..


   info  - socket.io started
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
glob error { [Error: EPERM, readdir 'C:\Documents and Settings'] errno: 50, code: 'EPERM', path: 'C:\\Documents and Settings' }
glob error { [Error: EPERM, readdir 'C:\Documents and Settings'] errno: 50, code: 'EPERM', path: 'C:\\Documents and Settings' }
glob error { [Error: EPERM, readdir 'C:\System Volume Information']
  errno: 50,
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: 'C:\\System Volume Information' }
glob error { [Error: EPERM, readdir 'C:\System Volume Information']

Comment: I am facing the same issue for port no. 9999 also.. the mentioned error message... errno 50 code EPERM.

Comment: Error message in console...

Uncaught NetworkError: A network error occurred. 
Request with id = 6 failed. Error: EPERM, readdir 'C:\Documents and Settings' InspectorBackend.js:271
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'frame' of undefined